# malloc sometimes fails. or pread sometimes fails

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

so I have a test program which reads huge amounds of data into a buffer and mallocs the 
buffer accordingly. However it malloc fails on huge sizes.

Is there a way to fix this?

thanks for any replies

the device /dev/sdc is a 2TB disk.

Here is ready 2 compile code:

```
#define          _FILE_OFFSET_BITS                            64     
#define          BLKGETSIZE64                                _IOR(0x12,114,size_t)    
#define          _POSIX_C_SOURCE                             200809L

#include <stdio.h>    
#include <inttypes.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <unistd.h>

int readdata(int fp,uint64_t seekpoint, uint64_t seekwidth) {

    int16_t  *buf;

    buf=(int16_t *)malloc(seekwidth*sizeof(int16_t)+1);
    if (buf==0) {
      printf("ERROR malloc(%"PRIu64")\n",seekwidth*(sizeof(int16_t)));
      return 3;
    }

    if (pread(fp,buf,seekwidth,seekpoint)==seekwidth) {
        printf("SUCCES READING AT: %"PRIu64"| WITH READ WIDTH: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint,seekwidth);
        free(buf);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("ERROR READING AT: %"PRIu64"| WITH READ WIDTH: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint,seekwidth);
        free(buf);
        return 2;
    }

}



int main() {
    uint64_t    readwith,
                offset;
    int         fp=open("/dev/sdc",O_RDWR);

    readwith=10000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=100000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=1000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=10000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=100000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=1000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    readwith=10000000000;   offset=0;
    readdata(fp,offset,readwith);
    close(fp);

}
```

output on my system is :

```
SUCCES READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 10000
SUCCES READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 100000
SUCCES READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 1000000
SUCCES READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 10000000
SUCCES READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 100000000
SUCCES READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 1000000000
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 10000000000
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 100000000000
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 1000000000000
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 10000000000000
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 100000000000000
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 1000000000000000
```

and sometimes

```
ERROR malloc(2000000000)
ERROR READING AT: 0| WITH READ WIDTH: 10000000000
```

Comment: Since this is /dev/sdc, i guess it is a Flash drive? Maybe you are trying to allocate more memory than it has? Also, at what side does it fail?

Comment: it is a 2TB disk, I added the output on my system

Comment: You should print `strerror(errno)` on failure of `malloc` or `pread` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i would say you can't allocate the memory of size 10000000000, because that is 9536 MiB, and I guess you don't have that much RAM.

You may consider using [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/).

> The core of STXXL is an implementation of the C++ standard template
>   library STL for external memory (out-of-core) computations, i. e.,
>   STXXL implements containers and algorithms that can process huge
>   volumes of data that only fit on disks.

Answer (score 1):

The Doug lea malloc(dlmalloc) about the minimum and maximum size of chunk

> If n is zero, malloc returns a minimum-sized chunk. (The minimum size
>   is 16 bytes on most 32bit systems, and 32 bytes on 64bit systems.) 
>   Note that size_t is an unsigned type, so calls with arguments that
>   would be negative if signed are interpreted as requests for huge
>   amounts of space, which will often fail. **The maximum supported value
>   of n differs across systems, **but is in all cases less than the maximum
>   representable value of a size_t**.

The maximum chunk size could be(2^31) and its around **2147483648**.

So in your case the last successful malloc call is for 1000000000*2 is larger than above maximum value hence malloc returns the NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with the data on a whole disk or huge file, you probably want to use `mmap(2)` instead.

From the man page:

> `mmap()`  creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the
>   calling process.

```
int fd = open("/dev/sdc", O_RDONLY);
unsigned char *data = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Things get more tricky and dangerous if you want to be able to write to the disk, but this is also possible (see the `mmap(2)` man page for more details.)

Comment: that seems like I good idea. but how does it handle if I close the fd or the disk gets removed from the system?

Comment: Why would you close the fd before finishing with it? As for if the disk is removed, your program will probably get a signal like `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV` when trying to access it (which you may be able to catch and handle). If you think that's a likely possibility though, then you probably haven't explained what you are actually trying to do.